# New hard drives doesn't start

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I built a computer a couple of weeks ago and I have only had a 120GB SSD in it which have worked fine. But yesterday I got two new HDD (Seagate Barracuda ST2000DM001 64MB 2TB) home. And when i install them the computer can not find them at all. I have crossed checked the cables with the SSD and all of them seem to work, I also tried to only install one of the disks but that didn't help either. I can't even find them in the bios so I don't really know what to do. When I connect the disks and start the computer both of the disks starts to spin-up for like 2 seconds but then they stop and I cant hear anything from them or feel them vibrate.

Does anyone have any idea of what can be wrong? If it was only one of the two disks that dident work I would probably blame it on the factory, but since both of them have the exact same issue it feels like I'm missing something.

Ooh yeah, I have a msi h97 gaming 3 motherboard and a 500W power supply from EVGA and the drivers are connected with SATA connectors. Using Windows 10 Education.

**Edit**
Yesterday I tried to update all my drivers for the motherboard to be certain that wasent the problem. And after i re-installed the same On-Board SATA AHCI/RAID Drivers that I already had in installed something relly  wierd happend. 
The disks would show up in Windows under Disk Manager but only as two 38,8GB disks and not 2TB as they shuld. 
When I tried to initialize them i got error message "The request could not be performed because an I/O device error". And if I would look at the SATA ports in the BIOS they dident show any disks on the SATA ports. 
So after a couple of houers of searching and trying to initialize them I tried to install the same drivers again. But after I did that I was back to squar one and couldent find them in Windows no more.

BIOS image of AHCI mode:

[image: Bios pic of AHCI mode]

BIOS image of SATA connectors:

[image: Bios pic of SATA connectors]

Comment: I'd remove the windows-10 flag because its not relevant if BIOS can't see it, and it will put some otherwise knowledgeable people off.

Comment: 1. Check the SATA data cable at either end and make sure it's snug. 2. Check to see if the SATA ports you're trying to use are enabled in the BIOS / UEFI 3. If 1 or 2 aren't the issue, power the PC off, disconnect the data cable from the drive (leave the power connector in). Does it continue to spin on boot?

Comment: Hi. thx for the advice. I have tried the cabels with my SSD that is operational and alla of them are working fine. I have also tried the SSD in all of the SATA ports that I use and with the SSD the ports seem to work without any problems. 
I did also try to take away the sata data cabel (read somewhere that the motherboard could send sleep signals) but I got the exakt same result. It starts vibrating for like 2 secounds and then it goes quiet

Comment: There are several builds of the Samsung 850 Evo SSD. Is yours a classic SSD in the form of a darddrive, or is it the M2 version. If it is M2 then check the manual, paeg2 25 which states `The SATA3 4/5
connectors will become unavailable when an M.2 SSD is installed.` Which could just be the port you used for both new drives.

Comment: Hi. Yeah I saw that aswell, but my user manual says that sata ports 5-6 will become unavailable. 
The thing is that i have tried the HDD with all six sata ports and none of them work. I have also tried to disconnect the SSD from the computer but i still cannot find the HDD drives in the BIOS.

Comment: If they stop spinning after 2s then it's probably not a motherboard/UEFI setting problem but more like the PSU/power connectors/cables or the harddrives themselves. Is it the same case without the SATA data cables connected to them?

Comment: Hi. 
Yes, the same happends ifi pulll out the SATA data cabels. They start for like 2sek and then they just go quiet.
I dont think the power cabels are the problem either cus when I connect the same power cabels to the working SSD drive there is no problem with the ssd.
I did however have a little progress yesterday. I have edited the main post with the info.

Comment: Can you tell the model of you PSU? Also, are the drives connected directly to the SATA power plugs provided by the PSU? Is there any splitter/adapter/extension cable in use? Are all three drives connected to a single "chain" of plugs? Tried disconnecting the SSD and connect only ONE of the HDDs to the power plug that SSD used, and see if the UEFI detects it?

Answer (score 0):

Boot to your motherboard and see what happens if you change from NVMe to AHCI (I'm guessing your motherboard supports something like this).

According to the [official motherboard link](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/H97-GAMING-3.html#hero-overview) that system "pushes your SSD to the limit with M.2 & Sata Express".   According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SATA_Express), SATA express "NVM Express (NVMe) as the logical device interface for attached PCI Express storage devices. While the support for AHCI ensures software-level backward compatibility with legacy SATA devices and legacy operating systems", which would seem to describe your usage case issues.

Comment: The motherboard is running AHCI as default so AHCI has been active the whole time.

Comment: At least i think AHCI is active by default. I am kind of new to this things so I am not so comfortable in the BIOS. But I snapt a couple of pics and added main post. Hope that helps.